# How can I re-add the database root node with Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase

How can I re-add the database root node with the Firebase Console after deleting it?

Please find the attached screenshot for reference

[image]

This is what I want to add back:

[image]

Comment: be ready for negative marking or edit your question asap :)

Comment: Hi mina, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry this first time to ask

Comment: What happens when you click on the "+" button?

Comment: Nothing happens, this for expanded node

Comment: Why so many downvotes? What you have to do I think: you see that URL link, just add something behind it and press enter. Than you can click on the + button again.

Comment: I do it but Nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not sure it will work) - create a file called "test.json" with the following in it:

```
{
  "myDB": {
    "data": "blah"
  }
}
```

Click on the three dot icon and import the file:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the problem with the network if you are connected from the Vodafone 3G network does not appear